# How to pentest a java application run through webswing?

Tags: penetration-test, java

I need to pentest a Java application through webswing. webswing allows running a java application in a web browser but how to pentest this?

I didn't find any documentation about this actually. With my HTTP proxy (burp), I can see that webswing used websocket but all of the traffic is encrypted or it is just binary data.